# ConcurrentModificationException with map of lists

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(br);
        int T=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        Map<String, List<Integer>> scores=new HashMap<>(); 
        List<Integer> zeros= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int t=0; t<T; t++) {
            //Begin solving here
            String key=sc.next();
            int score = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().trim());
            zeros.add(0);
            if (scores.containsKey(key)) {
                int curScore = scores.get(key).get(t-1);
                scores.get(key).add(curScore + score);
            } else {
                scores.put(key, zeros);
                scores.get(key).set(t, score);
            }
```

The code above is buggy in that it produces the wrong result; the "zeros" list is aliased everywhere (I think; I'm learning Java)

```
        if (scores.containsKey(key)) {
            int curScore = scores.get(key).get(t-1); //This line throws the exception; line 27 on my editor
            scores.get(key).add(curScore + score);
        } else {
            scores.put(key, zeros.subList(0, t+1)); //Here I fix the aliasing bug
            scores.get(key).set(t, score);
        }
```

Test input

```
2
mike 5
mike 2
```

Exception thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1415)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$SubList.get(ArrayList.java:1150)
    at div2.A.main(A.java:27)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "aliased". You are using a the same list everywhere (the list called `zeros`). Are you sure you don't want a unique list for every key in your map?

Comment: to Christopher Schneider: Let's say I have a new key at time t= t', I want its list to have t'-1 zeros and "score" at index t. But the way I did it, without noticing every key was carrying the same list.

Comment: I ran your code and couldn't reproduce the problem. See https://ideone.com/Gc8Xg6 - your code runs successfully to the end and doesn't throw this exception.

Comment: 3
mike 3
mike 3
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1415)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$SubList.get(ArrayList.java:1150)
 at div2.A.main(A.java:27)

Comment: I don't know how to format my comment here but the first 3 corresponds to number of input lines (denoted as T). "mike 3" is an input line repeated two times. the first time runs fine but the second one fails

Comment: Instead of adding relevant information as a comment, you can [edit] your question and add it (the full stack trace) there - where you can format it for readability. Also, you can clarify which specific line of your code is throwing the exception. Could that be line 27 from `A.java`?

Comment: Show a sample set of the data you are trying to read. Show an MCVE of reading that data and its output. Show the output you expect.

Comment: Sedrick: I had to google MCVE(loooll; thanks for making me a bit less ignorant); To begin with you read a line which has a single number corresponding to a number of examples (which is referred to as T), and the T subsequent lines are a name followed by a score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a misconception around this line:

```
    scores.put(key, zeros.subList(0, t+1)); //Here I fix the aliasing bug
```

You're not "fixing the aliasing bug". The method `subList` does not return a new list. As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) says, "The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa."

It then says: "The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list."

You're structurally modifying the list, since you add an element (`zeros.add(0)`) to the original list after creating the sublist.

You should create a new list instead:

```
    scores.put(key, new ArrayList<>(zeros.subList(0, t+1)));
```